# Check if two xmm registers have different sign bits

Tags: assembly, x86

How would you determine if two xmm registers have different sign bits?

With 64 bit registers I can do `xor rax, rbx` and check the sign flag. However if I have two double floating point values in xmm0 and xmm1 `xorpd xmm0, xmm1` doesn't set the sign flag.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `movmskpd` to extract high bits of XMM elements into integer regs.

Comment: Got it, thank you!